# JS How to remove an object from array in a forEach loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I have a `data` object with following contents:

```
{
  "content": {
    "id": "someID",
    "type": "unit",
    "method": "xyz",
    "blocks": [{
      "key": "blue",
      "data": [
        "Array"
      ]
    }, {
      "key": "red",
      "data": [
        "Array"
      ]
    }, {
      "key": "yellow",
      "data": [
        "Array"
      ]
    }, {
      "key": "black",
      "data": [
        "Array"
      ]
    }],
    "notes": "abc"
  }
}
```

I want to remove `block` that has key `yellow`, by looping over `blocks`, rest of the data should be preserved as is. So expected end result would be

```
{
  "content": {
    "id": "someID",
    "type": "unit",
    "method": "xyz",
    "blocks": [{
      "key": "blue",
      "data": [
        "Array"
      ]
    }, {
      "key": "red",
      "data": [
        "Array"
      ]
    }, {
      "key": "black",
      "data": [
        "Array"
      ]
    }],
    "notes": "abc"
  }
}
```

Data is dynamic so I dont know what would be returned, it might have a match for my condition or it might not.

I've tried a bunch of approaches but nothing seems to have worked so far. I can use `lodash` too if its any easier. None of those seems to be working. Any help/direction is appreciated

````
1. Using **delete**

const deleteUnwantedBlock = contentObj => {
  const updatedData = contentObj;
  const blocks = _.get(updatedData, 'blocks', []);

  blocks.forEach(block => {
    if (block.key.includes('yellow')) {
      delete updatedData.block;
    }
  });
  return updatedData;
};

console.log(deleteUnwantedBlock(data.content));```



2. Using rest operator:

    const deleteUnwantedBlock = contentObj => {
      const blocks = _.get(contentObj, 'blocks', []);
      blocks.forEach(block => {
        if (block.key.includes('yellow')) {
          let { block, ...restOfTheData } = updatedData;
        }
        return { ...updatedEntry };
      });
    };

    console.log(deleteUnwantedBlock(data.content));
````

Comment: Should be pretty straight forward with a filter 
`data.content.blocks = data.content.blocks.filter(o=>o.key==='yellow');`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: How to filter object array based on attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722159/javascript-how-to-filter-object-array-based-on-attributes)

Comment: I dont see it as a duplicate, I didnt know I could use filter before posting my question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to `filter`:

```js
const obj = {
  "content": {
    "id": "someID",
    "type": "unit",
    "method": "xyz",
    "blocks": [{
      "key": "blue",
      "data": [
        "Array"
      ]
    }, {
      "key": "red",
      "data": [
        "Array"
      ]
    }, {
      "key": "yellow",
      "data": [
        "Array"
      ]
    }, {
      "key": "black",
      "data": [
        "Array"
      ]
    }],
    "notes": "abc"
  }
};
obj.content.blocks = obj.content.blocks.filter(({ key }) => key !== 'yellow');
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Can I check something like `.includes` using filter? like if the key value is 'some thing yellow'

Comment: Sure, `({ key }) => key.includes('yellow')`

Comment: Great that worked! I'll accept your answer when SO lets me to :)